# Batch to toggle between showing 1 or 2 monitors

Tags: windows, batch-file, multiple-monitors

I am currently looking to create a script which will automatically change the 'Multiple Displays' settings in the display settings tab. I would like the script to change the currently selected mode form 'Extend these displays' to 'Show only 2'.

Is this specifically possible? Any help or guidance to point me in a direction is welcome, thank you in advance.

---

Edit:

The menu in question is this one: [image: Multiple Display Settings]

Found through the Display Settings menu

Comment: Take a look at [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/394601/change-display-arrangement-via-batch-command-line-on-windows-7) to see if it helps you out any.

Answer (score 11):

This can be done using the `DisplaySwitch.exe` utility that is in your system path (`%windir%\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe`).
"2" is your external display. To show you screen on this display only use:

```
DisplaySwitch.exe /external
```

Other possible command line options are:

`/internal` = switch to computer display only
`/clone` = switch to duplicate display
`/extend` = swtich to extend display

Calling `DisplaySwitch.exe` without parameters opens the display switch window.

Comment: While this does the job, it pops up the Windows UI for changing the display, which can be irritating. Still, +1 :-)